# Index(Match) for One:Many. A column that returns the list of distinct value in C for any instance of Concat(A,B)

Tags: excel-formula, one-to-many, index-match

## Count the distinct values in Column D for every instance of Contact(A,B)

Have tried:
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A1,A:A,0))

| Column A: County | Column B: Program | Column C: FundingSource | Column D: StartDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| County A | Program1 | 1234 07/01/2023 |  |
| -------------- | ------------------ | ------------------------- | --------------------- |
| County A | Program1 | ABCD 10/01/2023 |  |
| -------------- | ------------------ | ------------------------- | ---------------------- |
| County A | Program1 | TBD 09/01/2023 |  |
| -------------- | ------------------ | ------------------------- | ---------------------- |
| County B | Program1 | ABCD 10/01/2023 |  |

I have tried to use Index(Macth) to return the start date of a program using (Concat(A:B). However, this only returns the first instance of a start date for any program. Programs are funded through many funding sources, each with a distinct start date. Think: rolling admissions, etc.

Ideally, the return would be the list of Start dates for any instance of County x Program. However, a column that returns the Count of Start Dates for any County X Program would also suffice. The formula needs to be dynamic since the source data is always changing.

Any guidance much appreciated!!

Thank you,
Marissa

Comment: use [`FILTER()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759)

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you want.  Would you please clarify exactly what you want without explaining what you have already done?  I really think I could solve this problem for you, but I just want to make sure I get you the right answer.

Comment: Cary, thanks for the help. I need a formula that returns the count of unique variables when compared to column A. Column A contains only unique values. Column B relates to column A by 1:Many. Column C should tell me the count of B per any distinct value in A. 

Hope this makes sense,
Marissa